# Compute the integral using reasoning without converting them to iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The solid region E that is the right circular cone of height $10$ and diameter
$5$, sitting with its base on the $xy$-plane centered at $(0,0)$.

Use reasoning to compute the following triple integral without converting it into iterated integrals.

$$\iiint_E 4dV$$

I am not sure how to begin this problem without using iterated integrals? I graphed the cone using Mathemtica as well as the graph of the plane $z=4$.

Comment: $V = \int\limits_V {\operatorname{d} V} $

Answer (score 2):

The volume of a circular cone of diameter $\;5\;$ and height $\;10\;$ is

$$V=\frac13\left(\pi\cdot(2.5)^2\cdot10\right)$$

so

$$\int\int\int_E4dV=4V$$